# Implementação de Identity em projeto existente - Não funcionando

Tags: c#, asp.net, autenticação

Tenho um projeto de uma loja virtual. A loja já existe hoje feita em ASP e estou migrando para .net. Tenho a intenção de usar o controle de autenticação do próprio .net, porém quando iniciei o projeto, comecei um em branco (sem autenticação), e agora estou tentando implementar.

Já encontrei alguns tutoriais na internet que tentei seguir, mas até agora nenhum conseguiu fazer a solução funcionar.

Vamos lá para o que tenho pronto até o momento. Já instalei em meu projeto, conforme encontrei orientações:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Microsoft.Owin.Security
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

Já alterei meu model que desejo usar para login para ser o `IdentityUser`:

```
public partial class clientes : IdentityUser
{
    public decimal ID_CLIENTE { get; set; }
    public string NOME { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
...
}
```

Já criei meu startup:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;
using EmocioneJa.Models;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(EmocioneJa.Repositories.Startup))]

namespace EmocioneJa.Repositories
{
public class Startup
{
    public static Func<UserManager<clientes>> UserManagerFactory { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Cadastro/Login")
        });

        UserManagerFactory = () =>
        {
            var usermanager = new UserManager<clientes>(new UserStore<clientes>(new emocionejaEntities()));
            // allow alphanumeric characters in username
            usermanager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<clientes>(usermanager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
            };

            return usermanager;
        };
    }
}
}
```

Meu Controller está assim:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class CadastroController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<clientes> userManager;

    emocionejaEntities _db;

    public CadastroController()
        : this(Startup.UserManagerFactory.Invoke())
    {
        _db = new emocionejaEntities();
    }


    public CadastroController(UserManager<clientes> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

public async Task<ActionResult> FazerLogin(string email, string senha)
    {
        funcoes fc = new funcoes();
        string _nextPage = "";

        senha = funcoes.Base64Encode(senha);

        var user = await userManager.FindAsync(email, senha);

        if(user != null)
        {
            var identity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("ID_CLIENTE", user.ID_CLIENTE.ToString()));

HttpContext.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(identity);
        }
    }
}
```

O problema é quando chega na linha:

```
var user = await userManager.FindAsync(email, senha);
```

Pois ele nem sequer dá erro e nem vai pra frente. O sistema simplesmente trava aí.

Depois de apanhar um pouco, também tentei criar o arquivo `identityConfig.cs`, e na classe `ApplicationUsarManager`, mandei utilizar a minha classe própria (clientes), mas também não adiantou:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<clientes>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<clientes> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
}
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Se precisar de mais informações, me avisem.

Answer (score -2):

Então amigo, você está utilizando uma classe customizada para trabalhar com o UserManager. Você deverá implementar a classe UserStore para que trabalhe com sua entidade/tabela customizada, no seu caso a classe clientes.

Esse [link](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) explica bem como deve implementar...

Comment: Olá Bruno, o link que forneceu pode não ficar disponível futuramente, comprometendo a sua resposta. Transporte-a para cá de forma que atenda ao problema proposto pelo autor da pergunta. Inclusive ele está em inglês.

Comment: @Ismael seu comentário é totalmente sem sentido!